# Add custom item to radio button in extjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, extjs, extjs4

I have this radio button group in extjs

```
{
    xtype: 'radiogroup',
    flex: 8,
    vertical: true,
    columns: 1,
    labelWidth: 50,
    id: 'radio_group_id',
    fieldLabel: 'Group Label',
    items: [{
        boxLabel: 'option 1',
        name: 'rb-auto',
        inputValue: 1,
        checked: true
    }, {
        boxLabel: 'option 2',
        name: 'rb-auto',
        inputValue: 2
    }, {
        boxLabel: 'option 3',
        name: 'rb-auto',
        inputValue: 3,
        // is this somehow possible
        items:[{
            xtype:'numberfield',
            // number field settings
        }]
    }, {
        boxLabel: 'option 4',
        name: 'rb-auto',
        inputValue: 4
    }, {
        boxLabel: 'option 5',
        name: 'rb-auto',
        inputValue: 5
    }]
},
```

Is it somehow possible to add number field next to option 3 so that it gets enabled when I select radio button 3?

Or I have to use seaprate containers to align separate number field with the option 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can for example render `NumberField` into `boxLabelEl` of radio button. Another way is to create two column layout and in 2nd column put labels and numberfield.

Example of first approach: http://jsfiddle.net/NsbyD/2/