# Render custom Radio button in ExtJS 3

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I want to customize the radio button where I need to display text box, or Date field besides radio button instead of text.

There is a similar question [Add custom item to radio button in extjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13611280/add-custom-item-to-radio-button-in-extjs), but the answer is for ExtJs 4. Can someone please help me with similar implementation for ExtJs 3?

I tried using `contentEl`, but the div gets appended below the radio input tag, so is not visible. After looking at Ext code I tried overriding private `getContentTarget` function and it seems working but doesn't feel the right approach

Comment: any reason why is it rated negatively?

Comment: Your question is far too broad.

Comment: @royhowie it is specific to one use case. The solution in Ext 4 in similar question is simple enough.. Don't understand why it looks broad

Comment: The answer given for EXT 4 is working for EXT 3.1.0 as well..what is the problem that you are facing

Comment: @BhandariS doesn't work. `boxLabelEl` introduced in Ext 4 so gives `undefined` error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a workaround based on the ExtJs 4 answer. Instead of `boxLabelEl`, you can use `getEl().down('label.x-form-cb-label')` like so:

```
listeners: {
    render: function( radio ) {
        var boxLabelEl = radio.getEl().down('label.x-form-cb-label');
        boxLabelEl.update("");
        radio.field = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Number', {
            renderTo: boxLabelEl,
            width: 40,
            disabled: !radio.getValue()
        });
        boxLabelEl.setStyle('display','inline-block');
    },
    change: function( radio ) {
        radio.field.setDisabled(!radio.getValue());
    }
}
```

This should work for ExtJs 3.